# php failed to open strem

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I just installed my xampp, and I want to open a CodeIgniter project. But I get this error when I open this project. Can anyone help me?

> Warning:
>   require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\Requisition_Project\system\core/CodeIgniter.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Requisition_Project\index.php on line 315
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Requisition_Project\system\core/CodeIgniter.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Requisition_Project\index.php on line 315

Comment: is their index.php file in your project ? Also have you made any changes in your .htaccess file ?

Comment: yes, there is index.php , do you think the problem is in .htaccess? I dont change anything since I get this program. But lemme take a look in .htaccess

Comment: the .htaccess was changed, and I changed it back but I get Internal Server Error

Comment: you might have used different .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one in your .htaccess this one is fresh .htaccess file used in codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Comment: I've changed to that one but still have the same error

Comment: But when I add my CodeIgniter file name after rewrite base and RewriteRule the error change to be internal Server Error

Comment: I get "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace" in Apache error log

Comment: It was a fresh project ?